# dd completes implausibly quickly

Tags: raspberry-pi, dd

I'm running `dd` to copy a 1.8 GB image onto an SD card for a Raspberry Pi. This copies at about ~400MB/s, which is much higher than the write speed the manufacturer says this card can do. I therefore think that the image isn't copying correctly. Sure enough, when I try to boot off of this card, the Raspi fails.

However, when I take the exact same image, and dd it onto the same SD card using a different computer, it copies at ~6MB/s, but it works.

Here's my dd command:

```
sudo dd if=2018-07-14-test-lite.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M oflag=sync conv=fdatasync
```

Additional info:

- When I dd the image on the card, then read the card back using dd, I get the exact same image back. Here's an example of how I'm verifying:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M count=1704 | sha256sum
  ```

Comment: Are you sure `/dev/mmcblk0` is a device and not a file?

Comment: It shows up in lsblk.

Comment: Buffers at play, or @meuh has a point.  It can show in lsblk, but not be setup at the OS level.

Comment: You should check if the device exists after unplugging it. If it still resides there, then it's a file and should be deleted before plugging the device again. Check this [link](https://superuser.com/a/1413695/325072)

Comment: @SAMPro This question is a couple years old, and I'm not having this problem anymore. :) I solved the problem by using a different device to write the SD card.

Comment: Yeah, sure, definitely, but there are others have this problem like you and me.

Answer (score 4):

After `dd` finished writing that fast, the main part of the data are in a buffer (in RAM).

- Flush the buffer with the command **`sync`**

Wait until `sync` finishes and the shell returns to prompt. After that the data should be stored in the card. Now you can unplug it and move it to the RPi, and you can expect that it will work.

Comment: Why is `oflag=sync` not sufficient?

Comment: From `man dd`: sync:   pad  every  input block with NULs to ibs-size; when used with block or unblock, pad with spaces rather than NULs. This is not doing the same thing as the command `sync`.

Comment: @sudodus I think that's for `conv=sync`. From the manpage: `Each FLAG symbol may be: [...] sync   likewise, but also for metadata`

Comment: Does the sync command do anything on block devices? The manpage appears to talk about filesystems. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @NickODell, You are right about that.

Comment: @NickODell, I did some testing too, running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS persistent live in an Intel NUC with an SD card slot. Your command line needed no time for syncing (flushing buffers), while a plain `dd` command line needed ~10 seconds of syncing. It seems that some systems (maybe the hardware and its driver) 'see' the syncing that is initiated by `dd` while other systems do not see it, and the command `sync` is necessary. Do you want to see the output from my tests?